# procedure issue(error in syntax)

Tags: oracle

I have the procedure block:

```
begin
   for i in (select grantee
                    ,table_name
                    ,privilege 
             from user_tab_privs_made 
             where grantee='TEST')
   loop 
      revoke i.privilege on i.table_name from i.grantee;
   end loop;
end;
```

and the error occurs:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to issue the revoke as [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm), building a dynamic string with the command you want to be executed:

```
execute immediate 'revoke ' || i.privilege || ' on ' || i.table_name
    || ' from ' || i.grantee;
```